# Find out how many users are online in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net

i am developing a web application in which students give their exams. Here is requirement to show which students are logged in  in admin and faculty panel. First i have update a column in database named flag which turns to 1 on logged in time and on logged out turns to 0. But when browser forcefully closed it can not be updated. for this, i have used java script method,  which fires whenever we navigate to another page and shows the student logged out.

Is there any solution for the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to update your user's status as soon as he closed the browser without logging out. You could use the **Session_End** event in **Global.asax**, but that will be triggered when the session expires (usually 20 minutes).
Also, in Session_End you have no information about the authenticated user, only the session id.

If you are using ASP.NET Membership to authenticate your users, there is a method that does what you need

```
Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code on your **Global.asax** Page

```
public void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 // Fires when the session is started 
 Application["UserCount"] = Convert.ToInt32(Application["UserCount"].ToString()) + 1;
}

public void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  // Fires when the session ends
  Application["UserCount"] = Convert.ToInt32(Application["UserCount"].ToString()) - 1;
}
```

Add this code on your **Master Page**

```
private void Page_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
 //Put user code to initialize the page here
 this.lblUserCount.Text = "Users online " + Application["UserCount"].ToString();
}
```

**Or**

If you use the built-in `ASP.NET` membership provider, then there's the ever-so-handy [Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getnumberofusersonline%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method.

Comment: `Application` holds `objects`, therefore you can simply store the value as an `int` rather than doing all the conversion